# Need actual arrival time of Jet Blue 0165 from BOS on Jan 31, 2022

Tags: paperwork

Need actual arrival time for Jet Blue 0165 from BOS on Jan 31, 2022

Answer (score 1):

According to FlightAware, Jet Blue 1605 from BOS to RSW landed at 21:09 EST and arrived at the gate at 21:37 EST. Here's the reference: https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU165/history/20220131/1640Z/KBOS/KRSW.